# jQueryMobile non-modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

Is there any way to have a NON-modal dialog in jQueryMobile? The default dialogs created by jQueryMobile are default, and there are no options/switches for a non-modal flavor. Is there some supplemental JavaScript one could write or get to add a non-modal option, or is there a hack to the jQueryMobile JS to make a non-modal dialog available? Thanks.

Comment: Jquery Mobile is for Mobile devices.  I have not seen a non-modal dialog box on a mobile device.  Are you using this in a webpage?

Comment: No, not on a web page - mobile device, a tablet specifically. Many possible applications in which a non-modal dialog is needed in a tablet app.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by `non-modal dialog`?

Comment: A non-modal dialog is simply one that isn't modal. Modal dialogs effectively "freeze" he underlying window, preventing any interaction with it until the user does something with the dialog. A non-modal dialog, by contrast, does allow interaction with the parent window - even while the dialog is displayed.

Comment: Perhaps you can try using the [popup](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/index.html) widget instead.

Comment: Thanks, Jack, but jQueryMobile popups are the same as dialogs (one could probably find that a dialog is an instance of the overall popup class). So a popup too is modal, and has no means to make it non-modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good answer to your question has been provided by Gajotres in his answer to this question [Draggable Non-Modal Popup Jquery Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17811200/draggable-non-modal-popup-jquery-mobile).

The solution is a pretty intense hack into jQuery Mobile's inner workings.  It would be much nicer is this were a part of the library itself.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, Matthew. I tried it but couldn't see initially how it worked, but with more attention, i now see the solution and it should work for my needs. So, happy to see this, and thanks again for your attention to this - appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is great, but because it also include a solution for the popup to be draggable, it misses the point a little and don't give a simple answer on just preventing the modality. So I decided to add a clear explanation for those who needs it:

Jquery Mobile implement the modality of it's popup, by adding a transparent DIV which covers all the page. this DIV has a high z-index but this z-index is still lower than the popup DIV itself. 
In this way non of the elements under this transparent DIV can be clicked.
If you want to prevent the modality, just disable this transparent DIV by changing it's CSS and setting it's display property to none. 
The ID of this DIV is the same ID as the popup with "-screen" suffix.

```
<style>
    .PopupID-screen {
       display:none;
    }
</style>
```