# Draggable Non-Modal Popup Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I want to have a popup in Jquery mobile that would not stop users from interacting with a page and data-dismissible="false" that is the popup would not disappear when another part of the page is interacted with and stays visible.

I have tried this

```
 $('#popupNew').popup({ dismissible: false });
 $('#popupNew').popup('open');
```

But this creates a modal popup that prevents users from interacting with rest of the page.

Comment: Check out for JQuery UI lib, they got a good "Dialog" widget for easy build of popup :) !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Intro

I hope this is everything you need.

- Popup can not be closed if surface outside of it is clicked
- Elements below popup are now accessible
- Popup is draggable (tested on Firefox, Chrome, Android Chrome)

Few more notes. Some of a javascript code used here is not mine, I am talking about a fix used to make it draggable on mobile devices. Unfortunately I can't remember whose solution it is.

CSS is used to make page clickable when popup is opened. Overlay div name is combination of popup id and suffix -screen, in this case it is **`#popupBasic-screen`**.

## Working example

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/tMpf7/

## Code used

#### HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
        <!--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>-->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>              
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="index">
            <div data-theme="b" data-role="header">
                <h1>Index page</h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">
                <a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-transition="pop" >Basic Popup</a>
                <a data-role="button" id="test">click me</a>                
                <div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic" data-dismissible="false">
                    <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>
                    <p>This is a completely basic popup, no options set.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

#### Javascript :

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
    $('#popupBasic').draggable({
        cursor: 'move'
    });
    $(document).on('click', '#test', function(){ 
        alert('Successful click!');
    });
});

// This is a fix for mobile devices,, rest of the code is not mine

/iPad|iPhone|Android/.test( navigator.userAgent ) && (function( $ ) {

var proto =  $.ui.mouse.prototype,
_mouseInit = proto._mouseInit;

$.extend( proto, {
    _mouseInit: function() {
        this.element
        .bind( "touchstart." + this.widgetName, $.proxy( this, "_touchStart" ) );
        _mouseInit.apply( this, arguments );
    },

    _touchStart: function( event ) {
         this.element
        .bind( "touchmove." + this.widgetName, $.proxy( this, "_touchMove" ) )
        .bind( "touchend." + this.widgetName, $.proxy( this, "_touchEnd" ) );

        this._modifyEvent( event );

        $( document ).trigger($.Event("mouseup")); //reset mouseHandled flag in ui.mouse
        this._mouseDown( event );

        //return false;           
    },

    _touchMove: function( event ) {
        this._modifyEvent( event );
        this._mouseMove( event );   
    },

    _touchEnd: function( event ) {
        this.element
        .unbind( "touchmove." + this.widgetName )
        .unbind( "touchend." + this.widgetName );
        this._mouseUp( event ); 
    },

    _modifyEvent: function( event ) {
        event.which = 1;
        var target = event.originalEvent.targetTouches[0];
        event.pageX = target.clientX;
        event.pageY = target.clientY;
    }

});

})( jQuery );
```

#### CSS:

```
#popupBasic-screen {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: What I need is a non-modal popup, Thank you for your css!

Comment: If I put any buttons inside this modal, they can't be pushed. Any suggestions on how to fix that? edit: NVM. Got it working by applying a handle: "[data-role='header']" into the popup. Drags and the buttons work whoohooo :)